# Escaping special characters in a string using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

Can you please help me to achieve the below scenario using terraform?
I need to prefix every special character in a string value with //.

Example : `mysplchr="test O'riel*abc"` this has to be changed as `"test O//'riel//*abc"`

Thanks

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure what is the issue here, but you can write it directly or change the original string automatically if you want:

```
variable "mysplchr" {
     default = "test O//'riel//*abc"
}

output "test1" {
  value = var.mysplchr
}

# or to do it automatically for
# the original string
output "test2" {
  value = replace("test O'riel*abc", "/(['\\*])/", "//$1")
}
```

the outcome is:

```
test1 = test O//'riel//*abc
test2 = test O//'riel//*abc
```

Comment: lifesaver! Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: how do you do this one?  ```"${replace(var.name_prefix,"_", "")}cregistry"```

Comment: @mike01010 Please make question specific to your issue and errors that you get.

Comment: How to deal with case where youre assigning a value based on a template string which contains also a replace function call, which further may mean you have inner double quotes.  Errors are terraform complains about not being able to parse...right now only solution I found is to do the replace in a locals block and assign to a variable

Comment: @mike01010 Please make new SO question specific to your issue with relevant code and errors if any.